# Way too many disks in rEFInd?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, boot, partitioning, refit

I'm using rEFInd on my mac that is installed on its own partition. Everything works fine except when I boot into rEFInd (the "EFI Boot" option under the disk selection menu on startup) it shows my OS X boot along with about 9 other disks.

This is my partition mapping for my hard drive

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            396.4 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data REFIND                  4.1 GB     disk0s4
   5:           Linux Filesystem                         49.2 GB    disk0s5
   6:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                49.4 GB    disk0s6
```

And this is the content of my rEFInd config file

```
dont_scan_dirs

dont_scan_files

menuentry "Elementary" {
    icon /EFI/refind/rEFInd-minimal/icons/os_elementary.png
    loader vmlinuz-linux
    ostype Linux
    options "rw root=UUID=4CB3770E-E239-329A-90D7-189672FCD95A loglevel=3"
}

menuentry "Windows" {
    icon /EFI/refind/rEFInd-minimal/icons/os_win.png
    ostype Windows
    loader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}

menuentry "OSX" {
    icon /EFI/refind/rEFInd-minimal/icons/os_mac.png
    ostype MacOS
    loader /EFI/Apple/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}

include rEFInd-minimal/theme.conf
```

Is there any way to only include my OS X, Windows, and Linux boots in the rEFInd list? I don'y know where it's pulling the other disks from so I can't block them.

Edit: Here's a photo of rEFInd
[image]

Comment: I don't understand your question: you list one physical disc (`disk0`) and 6 partitions (`disk[1-6]`), and it is clear what the function of each is. That makes 4 other partitions besides those specifically for OSX, so where are the other 5? And the configuration file lists precisely the three operating systems you want. What's the problem?

Comment: It lists more disks than there are bootable (or at least ones I created) around 9 including OS X. Here, I only want 3. Where are the others coming from?

Comment: You originally said 9 others besides OSX. Your listing shows only 6, including OSX, and the configuration file shows the 3 bootable systems you want. Where and what are the other 3?

Comment: I've updated my post with a photo

Comment: OK, I see the problem now. I suspect the three hashed-yellow entries are unallocated free space of a few MB each, caused by aligning partition starts to particular boundaries, to optimise performance. The OSX and Windows partitions should be the obvious ones, and I guess the Linux partition is OSX recovery. Which leaves the 3 Ubuntus: one will be Elementary, but that still leaves two others. I can only hazard that these are the EFI partition and the physical disc, though the Ubuntu icon is a mystery. I can only suggest trying to boot each in turn and noting errors on any that fail.

Comment: Any way to block all except volumes explicitly specified in the config file?

Comment: It looks as though `dont_scan_volumes` may be what you need, according to [here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/configfile.html). You may also find other themes more helpful than the very basic minimal theme you're using, especially if you customise the icons.

Comment: You might also want to try `text_only on` while you are trying to get it working as you want.

Comment: I'm rEFInd's maintainer, and AFH is on the right track: First, use a theme that shows the name of the boot option. That will provide information you can use to use to figure out what to exclude via `dont_scan_files`, `dont_scan_dirs`, or `dont_scan_volumes` in `refind.conf`. I would also suggest that manual boot stanzas are probably unnecessary for you, so I wouldn't use them; they just add clutter, not functionality. If you're not booting any BIOS-mode OSes, you can also uncomment the `scanfor` line in `refind.conf` and ensure that it does *not* have the `hdbios` option.

Comment: I was able to figure it out in text mode! Turns out there were multiple boot entries for the systems. Some in EFI/ and some in boot/. So I just told rEFInd to ignore the EFI/ dir and it's clean now! Thanks!